# Can multiple firewalld zones be active at any given time?

Tags: centos, iptables, centos7, firewalld

I've been struggling through some [weird](https://serverfault.com/questions/654066/why-does-my-firewalld-configuration-on-centos-7-fail-to-start-and-show-iptables) (to me) firewalld errors but am now seeing the firewall behavior I'd like. But, baffling to me, what works seems to be a mix of both the `drop` zone and the `trusted`

```
[root@douglasii ~]#  firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
drop
  interfaces: eth0 veth879317c vethaff7c39 vethb2fec6e
trusted
  sources: 192.168.0.0/16
[root@douglasii ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=drop --list-all
drop (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0 veth879317c vethaff7c39 vethb2fec6e
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 443/tcp 80/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

[root@douglasii ~]# firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --list-all
trusted
  interfaces: 
  sources: 192.168.0.0/16
  services: ssh
  ports: 443/tcp 80/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I was under the impression that you set zones one at a time using `set-default-zone`. I see whichever one I do that for gets the "active" label. Is that not the case? Can multiple firewalld zones active at any given time? Do they all apply at the same time? What is a default zone? It's not clear to me from reading [the docs on FirewallD](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD).

Comment: you can also activate more zones by adding sources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my recent experience,  you  can have

1. A DEFAULT zone
2. Zones bound to (a) interface(s)

So if you have multiple interfaces you can assign each to its own  zone or all interfaces to one zone,  manipulate individual zones (thereby the interfaces) independently,  and still have a default zone  different from what the interfaces are assigned. The default zone i believe would come in handy to catch an interface thats not been assigned to any zone.