# linode centos 7 firewalld change-interface command failed

Tags: centos, vps, centos7, linode, firewalld

I just build centos7, and tried to setup firewalld, when I type command

```
firewall-cmd --zone=internal --change-interface=eth0
```

I got error : `Error: COMMAND_FAILED`

I already start it by

```
systemctl start firewalld.service
```

and `firewall-cmd --state` it's running

I don't know why ? and I can't find how to solve it ...
is there anything wrong with this centos version or do I miss something??

I don't see any command before , related  this firewalld setup error, list all:

```
yum update
```

update gcc

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install devtoolset-3-toolchain
scl enable devtoolset-3 bash
```

install nginx

```
yum install epel-release
yum install nginx
systemctl start nginx
systemctl enable nginx
```

install postgres

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.5/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos95-9.5-2.noarch.rpm
yum install postgresql95-server postgresql95
/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/postgresql95-setup initdb
systemctl start postgresql-9.5.service
systemctl enable postgresql-9.5.service
```

install mongodb

```
...
```

install nodejs

```
...
```

firewalld

```
systemctl start firewalld.service
systemctl enable firewalld.service

firewall-cmd --zone=internal --change-interface=eth0
```

UPDATE

after I tried firewald reload  , I can't use ssh connect now,

```
ssh: connect to host ... port 22: Connection refused
```

how to connect and fix firewalld ??

Answer (score 0):

To reconnect to your server, you can go to "Remote Access" tab on your linode machine, and go to "Launch Lish Console",

Please check this [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/654066/why-does-my-firewalld-configuration-on-centos-7-fail-to-start-and-show-iptables) looks similar to yours, as linode's kernel mismatch the firewall required modules,

Comment: thanks for reply I login success, stop and disable firewalld. I read that post before, and I tried `yum install kernel` it shows already installed, nothing happen, still same error ...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few questions to answer. Seems like you followed a tutorial and did not get everything right.

- Are you sure the name of your interface is `eth0` . Find out.
- As suggested go to Linode's `Networking` tab in the management portal and launch `lish` for remote access. This is like KVM so even if you an't SSH you can directly access the terminal.
- unless you specify `--permanent` parameter to your `firewall-cmd` it is not really permanent. Restarting the firewall will reset to original defaults.
- Check your existing rules with `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones` Some basic ports are unblocked usually
- optionally `alias` the `firewall-cmd` to something short. Looks like you will be using a lot of it :)

Comment: Thanks for reply, - I tried find out eth0, it is.  - I login via lish, stop and disable firewalld, then I can use ssh login now.  - I still don't know why got error, I paste all command I type in question, and it's new disk (I also tried rebuld and do it again, got same result) . The weird thing is I did this couple month ago in another I canceled linode account, and it works.